# Dos variables de sesión me funcionan pero la tercera no

Tags: php, session

Creo 3 variables de sesión y me salen en una página, pero si quiero usarlas en otra, sólo puedo usar dos.

```
if(($fila=mysqli_fetch_row($resultados))==true){
//while(($fila=mysqli_fetch_row($resultados))==true){
if($fila[1]=$password){
    $_SESSION["login"] = "logueado";
    $_SESSION["usuario"] = $fila[0];
    $_SESSION["foto"] = $fila[2];

    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo "Sesión creada ";
    echo "Bienvenido ". $_SESSION['usuario']."   ";
    ?><img src="<?php echo "$_SESSION[foto]"; ?>" width="50" height="50" /><?php


}
else{
    echo "Password incorrecto";
    ?><a href="session_index.php">Logguearse</a><?php
}
}
```

Y aquí trato de usar [foto] pero no puedo:

```
  <?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"]))
{
    echo $_SESSION['usuario']."   ";
    if(isset($_SESSION["foto"]))
    {
        ?><img src="<?php echo "$_SESSION[foto]"; ?>" width="50" height="50" /><?php
    }
}
```

Esto es lo que sale:

```
Primera: Array ( [login] => logueado [usuario] => jhon [foto] => img\Jhon2.jpg ) Sesión creada Bienvenido jhon

Segunda: Array ( [login] => logueado [usuario] => jhon ) jhon
```

Comment: no se si te equivocaste al copiar aqui tu codigo o no, pero faltarian las comillas en ´foto´ que tienes en esta linea: ´?><img src="<?php echo "$_SESSION[foto]"; ?>" width="50" height="50" /><?php´

Comment: uno de los problemas es que tienes puesto esto `?><img src="<?php echo "$_SESSION[foto]"; ?>" width="50" height="50" /><?php`, `$_SESSION[foto]` lo tienes mal puesto, debería ser `$_SESSION['foto']`

Comment: puedes intentar hacer un var_dump($_SESSION) y ver que sale para ver si trae información del parámetro foto desaparecido en la segunda página

Comment: El segundo `if` tiene un = de menos y siempre se entrará en él porque no es una comparación sino una asignación.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que **añadir** comillas simples a `foto` y **eliminar** las comillas dobles que contienen `$_SESSION` en la linea:

```
<img src="<?php echo "$_SESSION[foto]"; ?>" width="50" height="50" /><?php
```

De tal forma que quede:

```
<img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['foto']; ?>" width="50" height="50" /><?php
```

O como bien ha señalado @enrique manzano gil, también se podrían usar comillas dobles: `$_SESSION["foto"]`.

Además **asegúrate** de tener `session_start();` en tu primera página antes de crear tus variables de `$_SESSION` .

Comment: Básicamente, sí, pero el hecho de que sean comillas simples o dobles da igual realmente.

Comment: Sí, podría ser `$_SESSION['foto'];` o `$_SESSION["foto"];` , pero las comillas dobles que contienen `"$_SESSION"` deberían producir un error dejándolas donde están actualmente.

Comment: Sí, eso sin duda :), solo era una pequeña ampliación a lo que dijiste, por no crear una respuesta solo para decir que qué comillas sean de igual xD

Comment: Sí. Gracias por la anotación, lo añado a la respuesta para que quede más completa :)

Comment: Siempre presente para molestar a los presentes ;) XD

Comment: Es cierto que hay un error en la forma de llamar a la variable para mostrar la foto, pero esto no responde a por qué no printa valores para foto en la sesión de la segunda página

Comment: @Carmen , supongo que será por no tener `session_start();` en la primera página, pero no puedo asegurarlo al solo tener disponible una parte del código. He añadido la aclaración a la respuesta, gracias :)

Comment: @Ferni en lugar de añadir “actualización 1”, “actualización 2”... quita la parte que no sea correcta de tu respuesta para eliminar ruido. Seguirá estando visible en el historial de ediciones, por lo que no hace falta mantener las partes incorrectas en la publicación. Lee [answer] para más información y consejos.

Comment: Correcto, eso era. Te agradezco Ferni

Comment: @Jhon Hernández . Me alegra que te haya servidor. Recuerda aceptar la respuesta si esta es la solución a tu pregunta.

Comment: Cómo? como acepto la respuesta?

Comment: Debes hacer click en el ✔ gris que hay a la izquierda de la pregunta. Las flechas hacia arriba y hacia abajo sirven para dar o quitar puntos. Es importante marcar la pregunta que resuelve el problema de la manera más completa para que si otro usuario llega a esta pregunta con la misma inquietud pueda encontrar la respuesta rápidamente.